# как вывести список из базы данной по одному id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

спасибо что vs создает с EF свои контроллеры с методами. там есть контроллер индекс и детали. в первом выводится список из бд во втором дедали по конкретной строке:
Детали:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var autoTestDetail = await _context.AutoTestDetails
                .Include(a => a.AutoTest)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AutoTestDetailId == id);
            if (autoTestDetail == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(autoTestDetail);
        }
```

индекс

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var dataBaseContext = _context.AutoTestDetails
                .Include(a => a.AutoTest);
            return View(await dataBaseContext.ToListAsync());
        }
```

мне надо чтобы вывелся список как в индексе, но по id. сейчас у меня в строке поиска передает нужный id-шник но я не понимаю как это правильно обернуть. вот такого франкекода я пыталась создать

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ListDetails(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var autoTestDetail = await _context.AutoTestDetails
               //  .Include(a => a.AutoTest)
                .FindAsync(id);
            if (autoTestDetail == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var dataBaseContext = _context.AutoTestDetails
              .Include(a => a.AutoTest);

            return View(await dataBaseContext.ToListAsync());
          //  return View(autoTestDetail);
        }
```

как видно я тупо соединила по своему усмотрению но вот вопрос. по id надо выводить с помощью закоментированному коду, а просто все по незакомментированному(и тогда id ваще не используется).

никак не могу сообразить  в какую часть контекста базы данных добавить этот поиск по индексу.
у меня все время ошибки. хэлп

Comment: `await _context.AutoTestDetails.Include(a => a.AutoTest).Where(x => x.AutoTestDetailId == id).ToListAsync()` - не?

Comment: да, сработало, только x => x.AutoTestId == id. но это уже потому что на словах работу проги сложно объяснить иногда :) огромное спасибо